# Fill up to duplicate ranges

Tags: code-golf, array, integer

Let \$L\$ be a list of positive integers with no particular ordering, and which can contain duplicates. Write a program or function which outputs a list of positive integers \$M\$ (whose ordering is unimportant) such that merging \$L\$ and \$M\$ results into the smallest list which can entirely split into identical ranges of integers \$[1..i]\$, where \$i\$ is the biggest element in \$L\$

#### Example

Let `L = [5,3,3,2,7]`. The maximum element of `L` is `7`. The most times a specific integer occurs is `2` (`3` appears 2 times). Therefore, we need to output the list `M` that will allow to complete `L` so that we can construct `2` ranges of integers from `1` to `7`.

Therefore, we need to output `M = [1,1,2,4,4,5,6,6,7]`, so that each integer from `1` to `7` appears `2` times.

#### Inputs and outputs

- Use anything in your language that is similar to lists. The data structure used for the input and the output must be the same.
- The input list will contain only positive integers.
- The input list will not be empty.
- You **cannot** assume the input list is sorted.
- The ordering in the output list is unimportant.

#### Test cases

```
Input                  Output
[1]                    []
[7]                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 1, 1]              []
[1, 8]                 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[3, 3, 3, 3]           [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[5, 2, 4, 5, 2]        [1, 1, 3, 3, 4]
[5, 2, 4, 5, 5]        [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
[5, 3, 3, 2, 7]        [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7]
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Just to be clear, as your test cases and statement contradict each other, is `i` the biggest element of `L` or `M`?

Comment: @Kroppeb `i` is the biggest element of `L`, it was a typo in the specs.

Comment: Is it OK to return `M=[1,1,2,2,3]` for `L=[3]` while "merging L and M results in a list which can entirely split into identical ranges of integers [1..i]"?

Comment: @tsh No, it should return `[1,2]`. I will clarify it so that it's clear it should result in the minimum number of ranges.

Comment: I suggest you to add your first example [5,3,3,2,7] among the test cases, since it's the only one with the maximum value != maximum repeated one

Comment: @digEmAll Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan). The footer calls the main link, sorts the result to match the test cases and formats the output as a grid.

```
RṀẋLƙ`Ṁœ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4c6Gh7u6fY7NTACyjk7W/f//f7SpjjEQGumYxwIA) or [Check out a test suite!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4c6Gh7u6fY7NTACyjk7W/X@4/eHORSqPmta4//8fbRiroxBtDiIMdRRACMq0ANHGOgpQBOKZ6igY6SiY6CiAGOgCprEA)

#### Alternatives

```
ṀRẋLƙ`Ṁœ-
RṀẋṢŒɠṀƊœ-
ṀRẋṢŒɠṀƊœ-
LƙɓṀRẋṀœ-⁸
LƙɓRṀẋṀœ-⁸
```

[Try one of them online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4c6Gh7u6H@5cdHTSyQVAzrGuo5N1/x9uB4qoPGpa4/7/f7RhrI5CtDmIMNRRACEo0wJEG@soQBGIZ6qjYKSjYKKjAGKgC5jGAgA)

#### Explanation

```
ṀRẋLƙ`Ṁœ-   Full program. N = Input.
ṀR          Range from 1 to max(N): [1 ... max(N)]
   Lƙ`      Map length over groups formed by identical elements.
  ẋ         Repeat the range T times, for each T in the result of the above.
      Ṁ     Maximum. Basically, get the range repeat max(^^) times.
       œ-   Multiset difference with N.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>37</s> 33 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to nwellnhof!*

```perl6
{^.keys.max+1 xx.values.max∖$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzpOLzu1slgvN7FC21ChokKvLDGnNBXMf9QxTSW@9n9xYqVCmoZTYrqGoaamNReCa47KNdQBQnQhC1QBYx0wRBU01THSMdEx1TEFCv8HAA)

Anonymous code block that takes a Bag and returns a Bag of values.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                             } # Anonymous code block
 ^.keys.max+1  # Create a range from 1 to the maximum value of the list
              xx  # Multiply the list by:
                .values.max      # The amount of the most common element
                           ∖$_   # Subtract the original Bag
```

Comment: Nice! You can save a few bytes by coercing the second operand to Bag: `{^.max+1 xx.Bag.values.max∖.Bag}`

Comment: @nwellnhof Ah, thanks! I didn't realise the second argument could be the Bag

Comment: OTOH, the challenge requires that the data structures for input and output must be the same. With Bags as input, `{^.keys.max+1 xx.values.max∖$_}` saves another byte.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```r
rep(s<-1:max(L<-scan()),max(y<-table(c(L,s)))-y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9NbsIwEIX3PsUIFngkZ5GQFJSmN@AI2bjGaSMRB8WOFIQ4e@of1eKnINWazXyeN@/NMM@DPFJdJWnZ8YnuqkQLrigic@2pSgz/PEgq6I5pRExOOKewJURwQ1e16s23HMBIbUBwLXUJtarVCt/J0tNWfUGY8d8wakcsAM07CaLfS@AaODSjEqbtFSyaBWk@fls64ZmAfS5VlUSMk6f/zU4uhDQWpIhw95Ygp6MURu5LUGMnh1ZQ9MOb18N2G4OMwZpBzqBg8BZklrq6Fj/3sJPbO5tbjxsDBpsgW3vqKoofosXKYgVx4ZuwMgv6v8TBIH/UFM810S0GzK9XBJS5MxBe5A5W8ehwN5l/AA)

Comment: I have a 55 byte answer that basically generates the second argument to `rep` differently, but is otherwise the same as yours. I could post it myself but I don't think I would have thought of it unless I'd seen yours first. I challenge you to find it!

Comment: @Giuseppe: I don't know if that's was similar to your approach, but I saved 10 bytes :D

Comment: huh, no, I was using `split` but `tabulate` is much better!

Comment: mmh... now I'm curious, how did you use split for this ?

Comment: I had `x=max(L<-scan());rep(1:x,1:x-lengths(split(L,c(L,1:x))))` which upon further testing doesn't work for test cases like `7`...

Comment: You've just suggested me another 1 byte shorter approach :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>86</s> <s>83</s> <s>80</s> 72 bytes

```python
def f(l):m=range(1,max(l)+1)*max(map(l.count,l));map(m.remove,l);print m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDbDoIwDH3fVzTxhWlDssHEaPwS0geioCYMCEGjX49lU4OCbZN1vZyetnl057rSfX/MCyiCUm7tvs2qUx4otNmdAysll4NnsyYow0N9rTospdwNfxu2ua1vOQd2TXupOrB9EaQGI1aNCQGLXMBLUoWKwzGrwTVrQoLLFcFIRuUum/zLKgSNECHECAZh7bEQBqN5LE5taA7rCwjB84pccDCaTP6Y/pjrMc73QJomPR4vnpQamoPX7w2jN72Y@tF1BZ9OpO59rS38imLMXfyQEj@Tnw)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> <s>17</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ZLŠ¢àиIð.;þ
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Mr.Xcoder*.
+1 byte after bug-fixing the work-around..
-5 bytes by using the new 05AB1E version and -1 byte because ordering of the output is unimportant

Maybe I completely look past it, but does 05AB1E even have a remove all elements of list **b** from list **a**.. (EDIT: It indeed doesn't..) I know how to remove all multiple times, but not once each.. (multiset difference)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/yufogkOLDi@4sMPz8AY968P7/v@PNtQBQoNYAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/yifowsOLTq84MKOysMb9KwP7/t/eL3O/@how1gdhWhzEGGoA4QQhgWIMtYBQxDTVMdIx0QHSCJzTCEckCIjHZgJBkAjYgE).

**Explanation:**

```python
Z      # Push the maximum of the (implicit) input-list (without popping)
       #  i.e. [5,3,3,2,7] → 7
 L     # Pop and push a list in the range [1,max]
       #  → [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  Š    # Tripleswap: a,b,c → c,a,b, so input,[1,max] to [1,max],input,input
   ¢   # Count for each value in the input-list how many times it occurs
       #  → [1,2,2,1,1]
    à  # Pop and push the maximum count
       #  → 2
     и # Repeat the list [1,max] that many times
       #  → [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

       #Now the work-around bit because 05AB1E lacks a builtin for multiset difference..
Ið.;   # Replace first occurrence of the values in the input-list with a space " "
       #  → [1," "," ",4," ",6," ",1,2," ",4,5,6,7]
    þ  # Remove all spaces by only keeping digits
       #  → [1,4,6,1,2,4,5,6,7]
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Are you looking for: `K a,b Push a without b's`? Oh wait, "once each"... hmm

Comment: @JonathanAllan No, that won't work, it removes *all* occurrences rather than the first occurrence of each. Kevin is looking for something like multiset difference

Comment: @JonathanAllan Almost. `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and `[5,3,3,2,7]` with `K` results in `[1,4,6,1,4,6]` unfortunately. It removes all items instead of doing a multiset difference.

Comment: `¢ZIZLŠŠи` should save 1 byte

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks, but that wasn't the part I was looking to golf. ;p Funny how two triple-swaps is shorter than removing the access after the count..

Comment: If only either `Z` or `á` would pop...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yeah, mentioned that as well in chat about an hour ago..

Comment: @Riley Fixed.. As if the workaround wasn't long enough already..

Answer (score 3):

## [R](http://r-project.org), <s>59</s> 55 bytes

Using the `vecsets` package we can drop the answer length some. With `gl` we can get the ordered output. This doesn't work in TIO. Following @digEmAll's style of (rather clever) solution without a function definition, this can be considered a 55 byte solution.

```
vecsets::vsetdiff(c(gl(m<-max(L<-scan()),sum(L==m))),L)

f=function(x){scan<-function()x
vecsets::vsetdiff(c(gl(m<-max(L<-scan()),sum(L==m))),L)
}

f(c(1))                # expected: integer(0)
f(c(7))                # expected: c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
f(c(1, 1, 1))          # expected: integer(0)
f(c(1, 8))             # expected: c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
f(c(3, 3, 3, 3))       # expected: c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
f(c(5, 2, 4, 5, 2))    # expected: c(1, 1, 3, 3, 4)
f(c(5, 2, 4, 5, 5))    # expected: c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4)
```

Comment: digEmAll's answer is perfectly valid; it takes input via stdin!

Comment: Also, as this is not base R, this should be considered a separate language "R + vecsets" (I can't find the relevant meta discussion for that, but I know it's standard practice)

Comment: This fails when the maximum value is not the maximum repeated one, e.g. try `f(c(5,3,3,2,7))`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 98 bytes

This turned out to be pretty hard to golf below 100 bytes. There may be a better approach.

```javascript
a=>(a.map(o=M=m=n=>m=(c=o[M=n<M?M:n,n]=-~o[n])<m?m:c),g=k=>k?o[k]^m?[...g(k,o(k)),k]:g(k-1):[])(M)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDdisIwEEbv9ynmMoFppH/rUpz2CfIEYYRQtezGJLKKl/vq3aoothXDd5PwnTNDfuzZHtvf78MpCXGz7XfUW6qFVd4eRCRNngLVnkRL0WgKK93oKmBgSv6iCSxXvvFVK7EjR7VronG89o1RSnXCYRROSnRcDZcklZVhKbTs2xiOcb9V@9iJnTApw9OREhYLMPwxaS1ftVKEDCFHKBBKhM8ZNRQu4ffuofLFU/dIjLCcUfm1cAmPNnoke2TGltf3mzzjEXtzFm@RkqfjsvtP5Pe1C@7/AQ)

#### How?

We first walk through the input array `a[]` to gather the following data:

- `M` = highest element found in the input array
- `m` = highest number of occurrences of the same element
- `o[n]` = number of occurrences of `n`

Note that `o` is primarily defined as a function, but the underlying object is also used to store the number of occurrences.

```javascript
a.map(                      // a[] = input array()
  o =                       // o = callback function of map()
  M = m =                   // initialize m and M to non-numeric values
  n =>                      // for each value n in a[]:
    m = (                   //   this code block will eventually update m
      c = o[                //     c = updated value of o[n]
        M = n < M ? M : n,  //     update M to max(M, n)
        n                   //     actual index into o[]
      ] = -~o[n]            //     increment o[n]
    ) < m ?                 //   if o[n] is less than m:
      m                     //     let m unchanged
    :                       //   else:
      c                     //     set it to c
)                           // end of map()
```

We then use the recursive function `g()` to build the output.

```javascript
(g = k =>                   // k = current value
  k ?                       // if k is not equal to 0:
    o[k] ^ m ?              //   if o[k] is not equal to m:
      [ ...g(k, o(k)),      //     increment o[k] and do a recursive call with k unchanged
        k ]                 //     append k to the output
    :                       //   else:
      g(k - 1)              //     do a recursive call with k - 1
  :                         // else:
    []                      //   stop recursion
)(M)                        // initial call to g() with k = M
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
⌉⟦₁;Ij₎R⊇p?;.cpR∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FP56P5yx41NVp7Zj1q6gt61NVeYG@tl1wQ9Khj@f//0aY6RjomOqY6prH/owA)

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Kroppeb.*

#### Explanation

```
⌉                  Take the largest element in the Input
 ⟦₁                 Construct the range [1, …, largest element in the Input]
   ;Ij₎R            Juxtapose that range to itself I times, I being unknown; 
                       call the result R
       R⊇p?         The Input must be an ordered subset of R, up to a permutation
          ?;.c      Concatenate the Input and the Output 
                       (the Output being unknown at this point)
              pR    This concatenation must result in R, up to a permutation
                ∧   (Find a fitting value for the Output that verifies all of this)
```

Comment: You could use `⌉` instead of `ot`

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 72 bytes

```
import Data.List
f l=(last(sortOn(0<$)$group$sort l)>>[1..maximum l])\\l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYmxCsIwGIT3PsUNHRIIwapFB9vJUfEB2iD/YDWYpKFJwbePhoqL8MHdffeg8LwZk5K2fpwijhRJnnSIxQDTMEMhsvA5Lo6tDiUv79M4@zIbGN62XSWlpZe2s4VRvO9NsqQdGljy5yuYn7SLcuDoCqCrlMixW6ISyPzGfmkbgS/LrgXWAluBXP5VraCQ3g)

```
            sort l      -- sort input list
       group            -- group identical elements
   sortOn(0<$)          -- sort by length
 last                   -- take the last element, i.e. the list
                        -- of the most common element
      >>[1..maximum l]  -- replace each of it's elements
                        -- with the list [1..maximum l]
  \\l                   -- remove elements of the input list
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, 186 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;L->{Integer m=0,f=0,t;for(int i:L){m=i>m?i:m;f=(t=Collections.frequency(L,i))>f?t:f;}var r=new Stack();for(;m>0;m--)for(t=f;t-->0;)if(!L.remove(m))r.add(m);return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZFNTwMhEIbv/RXjDcwu2mqjFneN8WSyGpMejQekoNQFKszWNE1/e2XXjbZGIRDeZ/iYeZmLpcjns7etsQsfEOZJswZNzQ45wNERPIhEvQZ8VfC8QpVL3zhUAcjwogORDmQtYoQ7Ydx6AGDasBZSwX0rYefOykS8vE3xFxVKkOS/SEV5OrkZpCmiQCPhHhwUsK3yct3vAlscZzoN5NoHkl4FM6no2hamtFdmYrkuCBY3vq6VRONdZDqo90Y5uSJVZigt9RVONN8sRYBQOPUBUxTyjdDuQm7LY27znLYCC80xzxOhRpODigVl/VIRS2lgYjZLCx4UNsFB4JstbzNfNM91yrwvYOnNDGyyiEwxGPfy@ASCfvmTPEQy7EruxdmuGGap74PzXXmSdX0XjbNRdpql@S843oft4VF21jsO8ON5l3K3q7ecMfad9HQVUVnmG2SLVA/WjjgmSeviz69ehyBW7deSXywyETsuaGpfT2@2nw)

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.util.*;   // Required import for Collections and Stack
L->{                  // Method with Integer-list as both parameter and return-type
  Integer m=0,        //  Max, starting at 0
          f=0,        //  Max frequency, starting at 0
          t;          //  Temp integer
  for(int i:L){       //  Loop over the input-List
    m=i>m?i:m;        //   If the current item is larger than the max, set it as new max
    f=(t=Collections.frequency(L,i))>f?t:f;}
                      //   If the current frequency is larger than the max freq, set it as new max
  var r=new Stack();  //  Result-List
  for(;m>0;m--)       //  Loop the maximum in the range [m,0)
    for(t=f;t-->0;)   //   Inner loop the frequency amount of times
      if(!L.remove(m))//    Remove `m` from the input list
                      //    If we were unable to remove it:
        r.add(m);     //     Add it to the result-List
  return r;}          //  Return the result-List
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to [BWO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48198/bwo).

```
S-§*oḣ▲(▲Ṡm#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1j30HKt/Ic7Fj@atkkDiB/uXJCr/P///2hTHWMgNNIxjwUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```
X>:GS&Y'X>yGhS&Y'q-Y"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8LOyj1YLVI9wq7SPQPEKNSNVPqvGm0Yq4AMuFSjzTFEDHUUQCgWRcQiFkWNsY4CFMVCRUx1FIx0FEx0FECMWHQR09j/6CoA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

Input is a column vector, with `;` as separator.

```
llXQtn:yX>b-Y"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PycnIrAkz6oywi5JN1Lp//9oU2sFI2sFE2sFIMM0FgA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D8nJyKwJM@qMsIuSTdS6b@6rq56hEvI/2jDWK5ocyA2tFYAIQjLAkgZWytAEZBjaq1gZK1gYq0AYqDxTWMB) (this displays `--` after each output so that empty output can be identified).

#### Explanation

Consider input `[5; 2; 4; 5; 5]` as an example.

```
llXQ     % Implicit input. Accumarray with sum. This counts occurrences
         % of each number, filling with zeros for numbers not present
         % STACK: [0; 1; 0; 1; 3]
tn:      % Duplicate, number of elements, range
         % STACK: [0; 1; 0; 1; 3], [1 2 3 4 5]
yX>      % Duplicate from below, maximum of array
         % STACK: [0; 1; 0; 1; 3], [1 2 3 4 5], 3 
b        % Bubble up
         % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5], 3, [0; 1; 0; 1; 3] 
-        % Subtract, element-wise
         % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5], [3; 2; 3; 2; 0] 
Y"       % Repelem (run-length decode). Implicit display
         % STACK: [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
.-*SeSQeSlM.g
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.-%2aSeSQeSlM.g&input=%5B5%2C3%2C3%2C2%2C7%5D&debug=0) or [Check out a test suite!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.-%2aSeSQeSlM.g&input=%5B5%2C3%2C3%2C2%2C7%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%5D%0A%5B7%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+8%5D%0A%5B3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%5D%0A%5B5%2C+2%2C+4%2C+5%2C+2%5D%0A%5B5%2C+2%2C+4%2C+5%2C+5%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｆ…·¹⌈θＥ⁻⌈Ｅθ№θκ№θιＩι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzMvOae0OLMsNSgxLz1Vw1BHwTexIjO3NFejUFNTUyGgKDOvRMM3sUDDNzOvtFgDJgkSKdRRcM4vBUoDGdlAxUjcTDAvsbhEA8jStP7/PzraVEfBSEfBREcBxIiN/a9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Would have been 16 bytes if the integers had been non-negative instead of positive. Explanation:

```
     θ              First input
    ⌈               Maximum
 …·¹                Inclusive range starting at 1
Ｆ                   Loop over range
          θ         First input
         Ｅ          Loop over values
            θ       First input
             κ      Inner loop value
           №        Count occurrences
        ⌈           Maximum
               θ    First input
                ι   Outer loop value
              №     Count occurrences
       ⁻            Subtract
      Ｅ             Map over implicit range
                  ι Current value
                 Ｉ  Cast to string
                    Implicitly print on separate lines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```apl
∊{⊂⍳⌈/⍵}~¨∘↓∘⍉⊣¨⌸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CYb/04Dko46u6kddTY96Nz/q6dB/1Lu1tu7QikcdMx61TQaRvZ2PuhYDBXp2/AcrT6tOjH7U250I0tm7C4y2xtYqPOqdq1CcX1SiUJRaXJpTwlUClK8GSj3qXFgE0gVUaKWen63@qLtFPS0xM0cdorOolktDx1BTAQRKgIasAXLNYVxDBSMFYwUTBVMFMy5DBRCEqzJUsFCAqoKrUTDnMlaAQLBmCDSCQC5TIAlSZgSRAqkygQualiCphhhhomACAA)

uses `⎕io←1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 211 bytes

It's been a while since I programmed in Prolog. Can definitely be golfed further, but I have an exam to study for hahaha.

#### Code

```
f(L,X):-max_list(L,M),f(L,M,[],X,M).
f([],0,_,[],_).
f(L,0,_,A,M):-f(L,M,[],A,M).
f([],I,H,[I|A],M):-N is I-1,f(H,N,[],A,M).
f([I|R],I,H,A,M):-append(H,R,S),f(S,I,[],[I|A],M).
f([H|R],I,G,A,M):-f(R,I,[H|G],A,M).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BC4JAEIXv/Yo9KoyRlRTePKVQHewiiCxCqy2YLu6CHfzvNrtq2SGYw7w337zdEW1TNaUjOz4MhXWGxPadZ/6iFZcK5cUG7V4gzSBBtV4VFrYboNqhRp@NDHDqOx84@MIRhJBGfZAZ4kq4JJHjYm4I1x806uORHrNyIVh9RyqGm/7GDWeIz1FmJRxXTp/nYw2F/WmKHQbJFBXmSFpUeWnltexYS7uWK0YboXhTS0j1yXcm1MPa2BlG62w3A5JM/WHRu0B0/TrHhdwBmWphekC2QPZAdPPH92b/DQ)

#### Ungolfed version

```
f(List, Result) :- 
    max_list(List, MaxIndex), 
    f(List, MaxIndex, [], Result, MaxIndex).

f([], 0, _, [], _).

f(List, 0, _, Acc, MaxIndex) :- 
    f(List, MaxIndex, [], Acc, MaxIndex).

f([], Index, History, [Index | Acc], MaxIndex) :- 
    NewIndex is Index - 1, f(History, NewIndex, [], Acc, MaxIndex).

f([Index | Remaining], Index, History, Acc, MaxIndex) :-
    append(History, Remaining, Result),
    f(Result, Index, [], [Index | Acc], MaxIndex).

f([Head | Remaining], Index, History, Acc, MaxIndex) :- 
    f(Remaining, Index, [Head | History], Acc, MaxIndex).
```

Comment: Surprisingly not that long!

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 94 bytes

```
#(for[F[(frequencies %)]i(range 1(+(apply max %)1))_(range(-(apply max(vals F))(or(F i)0)))]i)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 234 bytes

```
#include<vector>
#include<map>
using X=std::vector<int>;
X f(X x){int q,z;q=z=0;std::map<int,int>y;X o;
for(auto i:x)++y[i];for(auto i:y)q=q>i.second?q:i.second;
for(;++z<=y.rbegin()->first;)for(;y[z]++<q;)o.push_back(z);return o;}
```

(Newlines in the function body are for readability).

The function takes and returns a vector of ints. It utilizes `std::map` for finding the max element of the input list and also for counting the occurrences of each distinct element.

Explanation:

```
// necessary includes. Note that each of these is longer than whole Jelly program!
#include <vector>
#include <map>

// this type occurs three times in the code
using X = std::vector<int>;

// The function
X f (X x)
{
   // initialize some variables
   int q, z; // q will hold the max count
   q = z = 0;
   std::map <int, int> y; // The map for sorting
   X o; // The output vector

   // Populate the map, effectively finding the max element and counts for all of them
   for (auto i : x)
       ++y[i];

   // find the max count
   for (auto i : y)
       q = q > i.second ? q : i.second;

   // Populate the output vector

   // Iterate all possible values from 1 to the max element (which is the key at y.rbegin ())
   // Note that z was initialized at 0, so we preincrement it when checking the condition
   for (; ++z <= y.rbegin ()->first;)
       // for each possible value, append the necessary quantity of it to the output
       for(; y[z]++ < q;)
           o.push_back (z);

   return o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 12 bytes

```
::⌉┅¤:C¦⌉&¤D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/38rqUU/noymth5ZYOR9aBmSrHVri8j/1UdvE/9GmCsZAaKRgHgsA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 177 bytes

Input and output are done through stdin and stdout. Both arrays are capped at 2^15 elements, but they could be as large as 2^99 elements.

```c
f(j){int n=0,m=0,i=0,a[1<<15],b[1<<15]={0};for(;scanf("%i",&a[i])>0;i++)j=a[i],m=j>m?j:m,b[j-1]++;for(i=m;i--;)n=b[i]>n?b[i]:n;for(i=m;i--;)for(j=n-b[i];j--;)printf("%i ",i+1);}
```

With some formatting:

```c
f(j){
  int n=0, m=0, i=0, a[1<<15], b[1<<15]={0};
  for(;scanf("%i",&a[i])>0;i++) j=a[i], m=j>m?j:m, b[j-1]++;
  for(i=m;i--;) n=b[i]>n?b[i]:n;
  for(i=m;i--;) for(j=n-b[i];j--;) printf("%i ",i+1);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LCsMgELz3KyTQoqgQW0IhG5MPCTkYwbKC25L2FvLtqYZeyjLszs4@xuuH9/seeBQr0oeRrVXKwAw3mq4zzaTmX2HXeoPwXDi8vaPAqzNW6uJGnERfA0opoi0sX4h9GmKb8mrUZpLyWEObALUGQXbOYz0NJbX0LxYSLemiQSyd15KtHe9YpVAaAdtezCaHxAVbT4wFLuC07Q275biy@xc)